# UISegmentedControl unrecognised seletor

Tags: ios, uikit, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add a `UISegmentedControl` to my app, but it seems that i always get `[UISegmentedControl longValue]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x22f44e00`

This is how i declare my `UISegmentedControl`

```
@IBOutlet var speedControl: UISegmentedControl

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    self.speedControl.addTarget(self, action: "selectedSegmentDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged);
    self.speedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}

func selectedSegmentDidChange(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    NSLog("method called");
}
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Uh, don't ask for the `longValue` of a UISegmentedControl.  (I know you don't *think* you're doing that, but if you examine the statement that gets the exception you will discover that the object you think is an NSString or NSNumber is actually a UISegmentedControl.)

Comment: The `forControlEvents` argument is a bitmask so I think you can't use that shorthand syntax? Does this work: `self.speedControl.addTarget(self, action: "selectedSegmentDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)`

Comment: @Jiaaro What you're suggesting is semantically equivalent to what he's already using.  The UIControlEvents can be omitted because the compiler can correctly infer it by looking at the addTarget arguments.  That it's a bit mask really doesn't enter into the issue.

Comment: I think there's some code in play that you're not showing us, since nothing here would result in `longValue` being invoked on any object.

Comment: @David I agree that it *should* be the same thing, but sometimes the compiler can't figure it out with the objective-c APIs. At least, I've had to write it the long way at least once to fix a compile error

Comment: @Jiaaro In any case, if that were the issue he would be getting a compile time error and not a run time error.

Comment: @David true. You're probably right, I posted as a comment because I knew it was unlikely ;)

Comment: Voting to close because you haven't used the exception stack trace to identify the failing line.  (Or if you did, you're not telling us about it.)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed none of my codes i wrote was causing the error, but it was the storyboard itself.
I right-clicked on the UISegmentControl, I noticed there were weird connections made to unknown source. I deleted them by pressing the "X", and everything is fine now

Comment: Funny thing, I had the same issue in my Storyboard! hahaha Glad I came here... lol